# mysql stored procedure doesn't writes expected data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

despite having experience in Oracle PL / SQL, I am starting to develop an application on MySQL (MariaDB) and a simple procedure that I just start writing is not working as expected.

Although perform the DELETE and TRUNCATE statements, the INSERT sentence does not result in anything when the procedure is called.

I'm making a mistake? Is there any parameter in the database that prevents the INSERT?

If you manually run the INSERT, everything works normally.

Advance grateful.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'192.168.0.%'
PROCEDURE invent.InicializaInventario(IN p_empresa varchar(4), 
   IN p_competencia varchar(6), 
   IN p_tipoMovEntrada varchar(255), 
   IN p_tipoMovSaida varchar(255), 
   IN p_dataInicial VARCHAR(10), 
   IN p_dataFinal VARCHAR(10))
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

/*
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Fase 1                                                                    |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  - Limpa registros de inventário existentes de processamentos anteriores  |
    |  - Limpa tabela temporária de produtos                                    |
    |  - Limpa tabela temporária de movimentos                                  |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    */

      DELETE
        FROM inventario
       WHERE     codigo_empresa = p_empresa
             AND competencia = p_competencia;

      TRUNCATE TABLE movfiscal;

      TRUNCATE TABLE prodfiscal;

    /*
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Fase 2                                                                    |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  - povoa a tabela temporária de movimentos                                |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    */

      INSERT INTO movfiscal 
                 (codigo_empresa,
                  data_movimento,
                  codigo_produto,
                  tipo_movimento,
                  codigo_deposito,
                  numero_documento,
                  sequencia,
                  descricao_produto,
                  quantidade,
                  unidade_medida_produto,
                  qtde_nota,
                  unidade_medida_nota,
                  classificacao_fiscal,
                  cst,
                  origem_mercadoria,
                  situacao_tributaria,
                  preco_unitario,
                  e_s) 
        SELECT mdoc.codigo_empresa,
               mdoc.data_movimento,
               mdoc.codigo_produto,
               mdoc.tipo_movimento,
               mdoc.codigo_deposito,
               mdoc.numero_documento,
               mdoc.sequencia,
               mdoc.descricao_produto,
               mdoc.quantidade,
               mdoc.unidade_medida_produto,
               mdoc.qtde_nota,
               mdoc.unidade_medida_nota,
               mdoc.classificacao_fiscal,
               mdoc.cst,
               mdoc.origem_mercadoria,
               mdoc.situacao_tributaria,
               mdoc.preco_unitario,
               mdoc.e_s
          FROM mdoc
         WHERE     mdoc.codigo_empresa = p_empresa
               AND mdoc.data_movimento >= p_dataInicial
               AND mdoc.data_movimento <= p_dataFinal
               AND mdoc.codigo_produto IS NOT NULL
               AND mdoc.codigo_produto <> ''
               AND mdoc.tipo_movimento IN (p_tipoMovEntrada)
      ORDER BY mdoc.data_movimento,
               mdoc.codigo_produto,
               mdoc.tipo_movimento,
               mdoc.codigo_deposito,
               mdoc.numero_documento,
               mdoc.sequencia;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is not correct:

```
AND mdoc.tipo_movimento IN (p_tipoMovEntrada)
```

I assume `p_tipoMovEntrada` is a comma-delimited string, and you're trying to match any of the items in it. But the list in `IN()` has to be a literal list in the source, it doesn't parse the commas in a string argument. Change that to:

```
AND FIND_IN_SET(mdoc.tipo_movimento, p_tipoMovEntrada)
```

Comment: Hello Bamar,

Indeed, the p_tipoMovEntrada parameter is a sequence of strings -> '001', '005', '017', '050', '105'.

Is that even changing the line to:

FIND_IN_SET (mdoc.tipo_movimento, p_tipoMovEntrada)> 0

It has not solved the problem.

Do you have any comments or suggestions?

Grateful.

Comment: Take the quotes out of the string, `FIND_IN_SET` just expects a string like `001,005,017,050,105`.